My VS Project .sln and .csproj missing after pulling from another branch
My project had a master branch and two separate branch for two users - branch1 and branch2. After merging the changes from branch2 to branch1, branch2 is now missing its .sln file and .csproj file. Same thing had occured to branch1 after checking out between the three branches. Now I'm unable to find the two files in the project folders nor am i able to open it from VS "recents".
Is this due to having both files in .gitignore? How do I get it back?
Tried looking for file in github, nowhere to be found. Both .sln and .csproj files were fine until the merge between branch1 into branch2 happened. Tried showing all files in the solution explorer, but still missing.

I had tried checking the git log but was still not able to determine what caused the two files to go missing. I had the project files on a flash drive and just added them to my repos on Git Hub and then pulled the updates on VS. Files are back but unsure what caused them to go missing. Guess it'll be a problem for another day...
Thanks everyone for helping!


Try to use `git revert -m` to revert your changes before merging.
Also check your .gitignore file for any other files that you will need it in your repository.
For more info about revert look at this.

You can get list of all the commits that affected your file in any way, thus to find where you messed up:
 git log --follow -10 -- my.sln

Here -10 asks to display last 10 commits (if that number of commits is present) that affected your file in any way (created, edited, deleted).
It will work even if the file has already been removed, ie is not present in your working tree at a particular head.
Having found out the culprit you can revert it, as aforementioned in other answer. You can use different options for reverting: git revert -m or git reset --hard, matter of preference and experience.
